# Update table rows with a number sequence with mysql_query()

Tags: php, mysql

I need to set a field in some rows to numbers in a sequence (0, 1, 2, ... ). Normally this should work:

```
SET @counter:=-1;
UPDATE nodes SET sort=@counter:=@counter+1 WHERE parent_id=2
```

But multiple queries with mysql_query() cannot be done. Is there a way to accomplish this in a single query or should I just run multiple queries in a loop?

Comment: use mysqli with mysqli_multi_query

Comment: @bwoebi I'm working on an existing code and it uses mysql, I hoped for a solution with mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing a join:

```
UPDATE nodes cross join (select @counter := -1) const
    SET sort = (@counter:=@counter + 1)
    WHERE parent_id = 2;
```